# Target multiple classes in a div and count number of times they have been clicked Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

The purpose of this is to be able to track the number of times a button with class testButton or incButton has been clicked and if either has been clicked twice to show a overlay.

There are 2 main issues:
1: I'm not sure how to select 2 different classes of buttons
2: Once there are more than 1 button with the same class name the existing JS code does only works on the first button with the testButton class.

The code I have is:

```
<style>
    #winOverlay {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 200;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>

<div id="winOverlay" style="display:none"></div>

<div id="buttonContainer">
    <button class="testButton">1</button>
    <button class="incButton">2</button>
    <button class="testButton">3</button>
    <button class="incButton">4</button>
    <button class="testButton">5</button>
</div>


<script>
    var count = 0;
    var btn = document.getElementById("buttonContainer").querySelector(".testButton");

    btn.onclick = function () {
        count++;
        if (count == 2) {
            document.getElementById('winOverlay').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `event Delegation` where you add event listener on the common parent container with class `buttonContainer` and you can check if the button clicked with id only `testButton` and `incButon`

****1)** `This code will work if you have to calculate of count of irrespective of which button is clicked.`**

```js
var count = 0;
var btn = document.getElementById("buttonContainer");
const winOverlay = document.getElementById('winOverlay');

btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const classes = e.target.classList;
  if (classes.contains("testButton") || classes.contains("incButon")) {
    count++;
    if (count === 2) winOverlay.style.display = "block";
  }
})
```

```css
#winOverlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="winOverlay" style="display:none"></div>

<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button class="testButton">1</button>
  <button class="incButon">2</button>
  <button class="testButton">3</button>
  <button class="incButon">4</button>
  <button class="testButton">5</button>
</div>
```

****2)** `This code will work if you have to calculate the count of specif key on which you clicked and show overlay if it's count is 2`**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("buttonContainer");
const winOverlay = document.getElementById("winOverlay");
const dict = {};

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const classes = e.target.classList;
  const addOverlay = () => (winOverlay.style.display = "block");

  if (classes.contains("testButton") || classes.contains("incButon")) {
    const key = e.target.dataset.key;
    dict[key] = (dict[key] || 0) + 1;
    if (dict[key] === 2) addOverlay();
  }
});
```

```css
#winOverlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

button {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.testButton {
  background-color: teal;
}

button.incButon {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="winOverlay" style="display: none;"></div>

<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button class="testButton" data-key="testButton">1</button>
  <button class="incButon" data-key="incButon">2</button>
  <button class="testButton" data-key="testButton">3</button>
  <button class="incButon" data-key="incButon">4</button>
  <button class="testButton" data-key="testButton">5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the condition "if either has been clicked twice". This just keeps a running total of buttons-clicked.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the correction, Answer updated using classList

Answer (score 0):

You need to select all buttons with querySelectorAll add listener to all of them.

```js
var count = 0;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#buttonContainer > button");
 
for (let index = 0; index < buttons.length; index++) {
  const e = buttons[index];
  e.onclick = function() {
  count++;
   if (count == 2) {
    document.getElementById('winOverlay').style.display = "block";
  }
}
}
```

```css
#winOverlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="winOverlay" style="display:none"></div>

<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button class="testButton">1</button>
  <button class="incButon">2</button>
  <button class="testButton">3</button>
  <button class="incButon">4</button>
  <button class="testButton">5</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select 2 class you should do as in css:

```css
querySelector(class1 class2)
```

But don't work because you can't use querySelector for two or more classes.
This code say only select class1 or class2 and take the first Element.

Use `querySelectorAll()` to have all of them

Answer (score 0):

As the others have suggested [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) provides support for multiple selectors. It will return an array-like nodelist which you can then iterate over.

```
document.querySelectorAll('testButton', 'incButton');
```

I'm going to offer an alternative approach using [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation) which allows you to attach one listener to a parent element that captures events as they bubble up the DOM.

This example also uses [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (basically a function that's returned from another function but that can carry any variables set outside it in the local lexical environment with it when it's returned. This is a useful pattern if you want to avoid global variables. In this case we create an object to hold the totals of the two types of buttons.

```js
// Cache your container and overlay elements
const container = document.querySelector('.buttonContainer');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

// Add one listener to the container which calls `handleClick`.
// `handleClick` sets up the object and returns a new function
// (the closure) that carries the object with it.
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick(), false);

function handleClick() {
  
  // An object that holds the button totals
  const cases = {
    testButton: 0,
    incButton: 0
  };
  
  // The function that will be added to the listener
  // It has the event argument
  return function (e) {

    // Destructure the nodeName/className from the
    // element that was clicked
    const { nodeName, className } = e.target;

    // Check to see if the element was a button
    if (nodeName === 'BUTTON') {

      // Increase the value in the object where
      // the key matches the className
      ++cases[className];
      console.log(JSON.stringify(cases));

      // If that value is 2 show the overlay
      if (cases[className] === 2) {
        overlay.classList.add('show');
      }

    }

  }

}
```

```css
.overlay { display: none; margin: 1em; background-color: #acaccc; black: white; padding: 2em; }
.show { display: block; }
button { padding: 0.7em; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #acacac; }
```

```html
<div class="buttonContainer">
  <button class="testButton">1</button>
  <button class="incButton">2</button>
  <button class="testButton">3</button>
  <button class="incButton">4</button>
  <button class="testButton">5</button>
</div>

<div class="overlay">Overlay</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName)
- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)